# text formattation of "description" array variable in graph protocol

Tags: facebook-graph-api

On the website I am developing, I'm using a function that get information about events taken from a group on facebook.
I noticed that using the graph protocol, the text contained in the "description" of the created array , there are strange characters like "\ u00b" or "\ n" for new lines.
How can I do to display the content formatted correctly?
thanks in advance
Piero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called `unicode_decode` ( http://webarto.com/83/php-unicode_decode-5.3 ), it will come out in PHP6 until then...

```
function unicode_decode($string) {

    $string = preg_replace_callback('#\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})#ism',
    create_function('$matches', 'return mb_convert_encoding(pack("H*", $matches[1]), "UTF-8", "UCS-2BE");'), 
    $string);

    return $string;

}
```

> Raska Top\u010dagi\u0107
>    Raska Topčagić

If you are not using PHP, sorry...

**Better solution:**

```
echo json_decode('Raska Top\u010dagi\u0107'); # Raska Topčagić
```

Comment: @PieroMaltese you're welcome, I've updated my answer with better solution :)